# How to know which ortholog database is the best for my work?

Tags: orthologues

I am working on four data sets of yeast genes and one data set of mouse gene. I need the list of human orthologs of those genes. There are a lot of databases available online which is in use for this purpose

https://questfororthologs.org/orthology_databases

I don't know which one to choose and why. Can anyone tell me on what basis should I choose a database over any other database? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To recover orthologous sequence for model species**

You should be able to find your orthologs using [BioMart](https://m.ensembl.org/info/data/biomart/index.html) and your gene IDs.

There are numerous way to do it, directly on the ensembl website or through API. You can start from these links (quite old though) :

- http://www.ensembl.info/2009/01/21/how-to-get-all-the-orthologous-genes-between-two-species/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EwfOQsr2O-M #Get orthologs via BioMart
- https://www.biostars.org/p/12245/ #Finding Human/Yeast Orthologs Using Embl?

**Which database should I use**

It is broad and depends on the nature of your work. In your case, working with "major model species", **DIOPT** (the first line of the table in Quest For Orthology) has the very feature you need on its front page for going from mouse to human. More eukaryotic/viral oriented database will be used for taxonomic identification, annotation inference, etc.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul!